# How can I add integers recursively in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, addition

So I wrote this code a while back but now I have to write it recursively. This program takes the input and adds it up.

For example `input=55` the answer should be `10`. If the `input=2645` the answer should be `17`

```
def sumD(num):
    sumofdigits=0
    while num !=0:
        sumofdigits+=num%10
        num=num//10
    return sumofdigits

def main():
    num=int(input("Enter number : "))
    print(sumD(num))

main()
```

The `def sumD(num)` function has to call itself. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I know it's just an assignment and all, but the sum of digits in a nonzero base-10 number is `(num % 9) || 9`. Whereas recursion is great, math is even better.

Comment: @kojiro: I don't see how it can be, since the value of `(num % 9) || 9` is fixed between 0 and 9 and so would fail for numbers like 19, 28, 37, etc...

Comment: @Dancrumb sorry, I should have said the *digital root*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def sumD(num):
    if num == 0: return 0
    return (num % 10) + sumD(num // 10)
```

Comment: This gives me the error maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just fixed it. No basecase! *facepalm*

Comment: Mmm, this doesn't work either. I input a number like 11 and it outputs 2.2222222222222223

Comment: Oh, does python do integer division differently? I guess that's why you had // before...

Comment: Fixed. But it kinda seems from the code you had that you should have already known what the issue was...

Comment: The default behaviour of integer division is changed in 3.x.

Comment: Oh. Fixed it. In the code there needs to be two `//` not one. haha

Comment: @JimmyLee Yeah I know it took me a while. haha. Thanks for the help guys.